# Have Lighthouse generate report using custom template

Tags: lighthouse

Is it possible to have Lighthouse export using custom HTML template instead of the templates provided in Lighthouse?

I was thinking there may be a way like [Basic Custom Audit Recipe](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/tree/master/docs/recipes/custom-audit).

I'm thinking the code for the template logic is [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/lighthouse-core/report/v2/report-generator.js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you switch to the gh-pages branch you can see that the report viewer is a unique animal by itself in a folder located at /viewer/.  Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Fork the repository at Github
2. In the settings of the repository, follow the instructions in the GitHub Pages section to publish your GitHub Pages site.
3. Edit and customize the index.html to your needs and commit.
4. Run a Lighthouse report and save it as a Gist.
5. Load that report in your new, customized viewer at https://GITHUB_USERNAME.github.io/GITHUB_REPOSITORY_NAME/viewer/?gist=GITHUB_GIST_ID